Unpausing timer triggered Azure functions caused them to run as "past due"
Two of my timer triggered azure functions just ran because i un-paused them. The logs state "IsPastDue" as their reason, but the original schedule is from before i paused them.
Executing 'My_Function_1700' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-05-24T07:03:17.9008486+00:00', Id=Blah1)
Trigger Details: UnscheduledInvocationReason: IsPastDue, OriginalSchedule: 2024-05-21T07:00:00.0000000+00:00

Executing 'My_Function_0005' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-05-24T07:02:34.1964332+00:00', Id=Blah2)
Trigger Details: UnscheduledInvocationReason: IsPastDue, OriginalSchedule: 2024-05-21T14:05:00.0000000+00:00

How can i change this behavior so that when i pause, any scheduled operations are removed, or alternatively when i un-pause an past due operations are ignored?
I tried reading the documentation but unfortunately i could not see a solution to my problem. In my Function both UseMonitor and RunOnStartup where unspecified when constructing the time trigger, which should mean that RunOnStartup defaults to false and UseMonitor is set to true, which is what i want.
Thanks!
